# JavaScript Validation for Google Forms/Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

It's been a while since I've done JavaScript, but I could just be having issues with Google Scripts...

I'm trying to validate a response to a Google Form. Essentially, we send out a form asking for a name, email and code word given at the end of a webinar. If the user responds correctly, we want to send them an email with a URL to a form with ethics credit. If incorrect, we want to send them an email with their incorrect response. Currently, I can pull all the data, but for some reason, cannot change valid to false...So far, I know that everything before "var valid = false" works. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
/* before this section - gets values from separate Google sheet
   and gets other responses from the Google Form */

var submission = itemResponses[2].getResponse(); // gets code word response from form

var newSubmission = submission.toLowerCase().trim(); // format submission;

var valid = false;
var month = "";
var url = "";


for(var i; i < range.length; i++) {
   if(range[i][1] == newSubmission) { // range is the range in the spreadsheet. 
                                      // [i][1] is the second col of selection.
     valid = !valid;
     month += range[i][0];
     url += range[i][2];
     break;
   }
}
```

After this, it just sends the email. I do receive emails, but they always come as the false response...

Comment: I suspect your issues stem from one of 2 things; It could be your range object or the value of the newSubmission variable. You should try logging their values with Logger.log().

Comment: I did try Logger.log(), but unfortunately one of the values above submission requires a form submission and will not continue the script otherwise (in run or debugger). I did figure it out though...I forgot that for loops are for(i = 0...)  in JS...I've been working in Java and C for about 4 months now, so it's taking me a while to refresh my memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a value to i if you want the loop to start
change this line: for(var i; i < range.length; i++) {
by for(var i=0; i < range.length; i++) {

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sorry, I forgot to take this down. You were correct, ClemT. Here's the full code, if anyone would like to view it.

https://github.com/AJax2012/google-form-validate-with-sheet